# Converting bytes to table in Lua doesn't work in 5.2.4

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a dissector for Wireshark, and want to use [aeslua](https://github.com/SquidDev-CC/aeslua) to decrypt some packets that are coming in. My dissector works fine, but aeslua gets caught up on a line that tries to put the password into a table after converting it to bytes.

The line in question is this:

```
local pwBytes = { string.byte(password,1,#password)}
```

This returns `null` in Lua 5.2.4 (which is included in Wireshark 2.2.4), but in the online demo (2.3.4 as of writing), it returns the expected value.

I tried changing it to:

```
local pwBytes = { password:byte(1, #password) }
```

But got the same null result.

For reference, he's the code I ran in the Lua demo:

```
local password = "ABCDEFABCDEFA"
local pwBytes = {string.byte(password,1,#password)}
print(pwBytes)
```

Is there a way I get around this?

Comment: The code works fine in stock Lua 5.2.4.

Comment: @lhf That's interesting. Might be a bug with Wireshark then. I might need to take this conversation over to AskWireshark as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine in stock Lua 5.2.4:

```
local password = "ABCDEFABCDEFA"
local pwBytes = {string.byte(password,1,#password)}
print(pwBytes)
for k,v in ipairs(pwBytes) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

gives

```
table: 0x7fc689d00560
1   65
2   66
3   67
4   68
5   69
6   70
7   65
8   66
9   67
10  68
11  69
12  70
13  65
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've also posted this question over on the [Wireshark Q&A Site](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/59347/converting-bytes-to-table-for-lua-dissector-doesnt-work)